# Как в коде определить, какая команда передана manage.py?

Tags: python, django

У меня реализован метод, запускающийся при каждом запуске сервера:

```
class MyConfig(AppConfig):
    name = 'app'
    verbose_name = "Main app"

    def ready(self):
        #что-то делает при запуске
```

Я обнаружил, что при запуске команды

```
python manage.py migrate
```

он тоже отрабатывает. Такая же ситуация и с другими командами, передаваемыми в **manage.py**, помимо **runserver**.

Как в коде отследить, какая команда была передана **manage.py**, чтобы прерывать выполнения если это не **runserver**?

Comment: Не уверен, но если вам нужно посмотреть аргументы командной строки, то можно сделать `import sys` и смотреть их в списке `sys.argv`

Comment: Уточните файл где находится class MyConfig(AppConfig)

Comment: Не по теме вопроса: вы случайно не забываете учитывать другие варианты запуска сервера, например через gunicorn или uwsgi или вообще как cgi?

Comment: @Igor в apps.py. Это класс, наследуемый от класса джанги, и переопределяем метод ready, который запускается каждый раз перед запуском сервера.

Comment: @hunter да, действительно, то что нужно.

Answer (score 2):

Если данный код находится в файле manage.py то все просто, там уже есть передача аргументов

execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)

Проверяем их на наличие нужного.

---

Алтернативные варианты

Создание своей команды управления рекомендуется чаще чем проверка аргументов.
Вот интересное решение, stackoverflow.com/questions/5942759/… одновременный запуск вида /manage.py clearcache && ./manage.py runserver

---

Создание своего способа запуска сервера.

Для этого создаем свою команду запуска сервера, частично код копируем из файлов [autoreload.py](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/utils/autoreload.py) и [runserver.py](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/core/management/commands/runserver.py)